# Summarize values of selected radio buttons in javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, radio-button

I have an html form with three groups of radio buttons, `selector`, `selector2` and `selector3`. I am trying to add the values of the selected radio buttons, but this fails. How Can I add all the values in the `alert` below? Why doesn't it work? I tried in a different way but I can add the values just get them in the console.

```
<script>
const form = document.querySelector('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', obtenerTotal);

function obtenerTotal(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData(event.target);

    const selector = parseInt(formData.get('selector') || '0', 10);
    const selector2 = parseInt(formData.get('selector2') || '0', 10);
    const selector3 = parseInt(formData.get('selector3') || '0', 10);

    const result = selector + selector2 + selector3;
    alert("the value is:" + result);
}
</script>
```

My form:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Ob Calculator</title>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="alert">
        <h2>Hey! Read Me...</h2>
        <p></p>
    </div>


  <div class="container">
        <form>              
                <h2>Ocular</h2>
                
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" id="a-option" class="radi" name="selector" value="4">
                    <label for="a-option">Espontanea</label>
                    
                    <div class="check"></div>
                </li>
                
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" id="b-option" class="radi" name="selector" value="3">
                    <label for="b-option">Orden Verbal</label>
                    
                    <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
                </li>
                
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" id="c-option" class="radi" name="selector" value="2">
                    <label for="c-option">Dolor</label>
                    
                    <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
                </li>
                        
                        <li>
                    <input type="radio" id="d-option" class="radi" name="selector" value="1">
                    <label for="d-option"><a href="#verbal">No Responde</a></label>
                    
                    <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
                </li>

            </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                
                <h2 id="verbal">Verbal</h2>
                
            <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="e-option" name="selector2" value="5" >
                        <label for="e-option">Orientado y conversando</label>
                        
                        <div class="check"></div>
                    </li>
                    
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="f-option" class="radi" name="selector2" value="4" >
                        <label for="f-option">Desorientado y hablando</label>
                        
                        <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
                    </li>
                    
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="h-option" class="radi" name="selector2" value="3" >
                        <label for="h-option">Palabras inapropiadas</label>
                        
                        <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
                    </li>
                            
                            <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="i-option" class="radi" name="selector2" value="2" >
                        <label for="i-option">Sonidos Incomprensibles</label>
                        
                        <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="j-option" class="radi" name="selector2" value="1" >
                        <label for="j-option">Ninguna respuesta</label>
                        
                        <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
                    </li>

            </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                
                <h2 id="verbal">Motora</h2>
                
            <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="k-option" class="radi" name="selector3" value="6" >
                        <label for="k-option">Orden verbal obedece</label>
                        
                        <div class="check"></div>
                    </li>
                    
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="l-option" class="radi" name="selector3" value="5" >
                        <label for="l-option">Localiza el dolor</label>
                        
                        <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
                    </li>
                    
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="m-option" class="radi" name="selector3" value="4" >
                        <label for="m-option">Retirada y flexion</label>
                        
                        <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
                    </li>
                            
                            <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="o-option" class="radi" name="selector3" value="3" >
                        <label for="o-option">Flexion Anormal</label>
                        
                        <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="p-option" name="selector3" value="2" >
                        <label for="p-option">Extension</label>
                        
                        <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="r-option" class="radi" name="selector3" value="1" >
                        <label for="r-option">Ninguna respuesta</label>
                        
                        <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
                    </li>

            </ul>
            <button>Obtener TOTAL</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="signature">

      
        <p></a></p>
    </div>
    <script><!-- javascript from above... --></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please edit your question and provide an example of what you expect as a result, and what you actually get as well? Something like: "If i select selector value 5, selector2 value 4 and selector3 value 3, I expect the result 12. But I get the result Nnnnn"

Comment: Sorry, I'm new on this. But you're right. I have to be more especific with the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add type="submit" on button tag at line 143.

```html
<button type="submit">Obtener TOTAL</button>
```

sandbox below:

https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-mclaren-bbxv4?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Ob Calculator</title>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="alert">
        <h2>Hey! Read Me...</h2>
        <p></p>
    </div>


  <div class="container">
        <form>              
                <h2>Ocular</h2>
                
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" id="a-option" class="radi" name="selector" value="4">
                    <label for="a-option">Espontanea</label>
                    
                    <div class="check"></div>
                </li>
                
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" id="b-option" class="radi" name="selector" value="3">
                    <label for="b-option">Orden Verbal</label>
                    
                    <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
                </li>
                
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" id="c-option" class="radi" name="selector" value="2">
                    <label for="c-option">Dolor</label>
                    
                    <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
                </li>
                        
                        <li>
                    <input type="radio" id="d-option" class="radi" name="selector" value="1">
                    <label for="d-option"><a href="#verbal">No Responde</a></label>
                    
                    <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
                </li>

            </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                
                <h2 id="verbal">Verbal</h2>
                
            <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="e-option" name="selector2" value="5" >
                        <label for="e-option">Orientado y conversando</label>
                        
                        <div class="check"></div>
                    </li>
                    
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="f-option" class="radi" name="selector2" value="4" >
                        <label for="f-option">Desorientado y hablando</label>
                        
                        <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
                    </li>
                    
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="h-option" class="radi" name="selector2" value="3" >
                        <label for="h-option">Palabras inapropiadas</label>
                        
                        <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
                    </li>
                            
                            <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="i-option" class="radi" name="selector2" value="2" >
                        <label for="i-option">Sonidos Incomprensibles</label>
                        
                        <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="j-option" class="radi" name="selector2" value="1" >
                        <label for="j-option">Ninguna respuesta</label>
                        
                        <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
                    </li>

            </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                
                <h2 id="verbal">Motora</h2>
                
            <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="k-option" class="radi" name="selector3" value="6" >
                        <label for="k-option">Orden verbal obedece</label>
                        
                        <div class="check"></div>
                    </li>
                    
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="l-option" class="radi" name="selector3" value="5" >
                        <label for="l-option">Localiza el dolor</label>
                        
                        <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
                    </li>
                    
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="m-option" class="radi" name="selector3" value="4" >
                        <label for="m-option">Retirada y flexion</label>
                        
                        <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
                    </li>
                            
                            <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="o-option" class="radi" name="selector3" value="3" >
                        <label for="o-option">Flexion Anormal</label>
                        
                        <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="p-option" name="selector3" value="2" >
                        <label for="p-option">Extension</label>
                        
                        <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="r-option" class="radi" name="selector3" value="1" >
                        <label for="r-option">Ninguna respuesta</label>
                        
                        <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
                    </li>

            </ul>
            <button>Obtener TOTAL</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="signature">

      
        <p></a></p>
    </div>
  <script>
const form = document.querySelector('form');

form.addEventListener('submit', obtenerTotal);

function obtenerTotal(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData(event.target);

    const selector = parseInt(formData.get('selector') || '0', 10);
    const selector2 = parseInt(formData.get('selector2') || '0', 10);
    const selector3 = parseInt(formData.get('selector3') || '0', 10);

    const result = selector + selector2 + selector3;
    alert(`Ocular: ${selector}\nVerbal: ${selector2}\nMotora: ${selector3}\nThe value is : ` + result);
  }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, something like that but when I tried to put in my code doesn't work. I don't know what happen. says: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at main.js:3

Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'form' has already been declared

Comment: Yes, when I put the JavaScript Code in Visual Studio Code and run the page the console show me two errors: main.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at main.js:3
and
Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'form' has already been declared glasgow.html?selector=3&selector2=4&selector3=4:11

Comment: `Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null at main.js:3` means that `form.addEventListener` cannot run because `form` is **null**. This happens when `document.querySelector('form')` on the first line of your script block returns null, because it cannot find a form element in the document. This seems odd, as you clearly have a form element present. However, I guess it is related to the uncaught `SyntaxError: Identifier 'form'  has already been declared`. This is caused by another const form = previously. Have you checked if you have accidentally included the script block twice?